# Token in URL parameter,How can I store in localstorage?

Tags: azure, token, azure-ad-b2c

When redirected to SPA from the login screen by ADB2C, the access token and ID token are embedded in the URL. (ex:https:[SPA URL]?access_token=XXXXX)
I would like to store the access token or ID token embedded in the URL in localstorage. I checked the localstorage in the developer tools, but it is not stored.
Is processing using MSAL required on the SPA side in this case?
Or can it be stored in localstorage with ADB2C settings, etc.?

Comment: If you are using MSAL, then you should not be concerned about storing this token yourself as MSAL will take care of it.

Comment: My login screen is completely independent and does not pop up in the SPA.
I go directly to the login screen URL. (ADB2C login screen endpoint)
In this case, I have the login screen redirected to SPA, can I get a token?
The official sample is SPA -> login screen (popup) -> SPA, which is not what I am assuming.